# Is it possible to downgrade oracle 11.1.0.6.0 to 10.2.0.4.0?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, downgrade

Is it possible to downgrade oracle 11.1.0.6.0 to 10.2.0.4.0?
The Compatible parameter need to be changed to "10.2.0"?
Today I have Compatible set to 10.2.0.4.0.

It's not clear on support.oracle if I need to change or not.
This document 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/upgrade/upgrade11gr2-downgrade-methods-179029.pdf

state:

> The major restriction on the downgrade script is that it cannot be run
>   if the COMPATIBLE parameter has been raised as part of, or after, the
>   upgrade. This is because raising the COMPATIBLE parameter will allow
>   on-disk changes that cannot be understood by the earlier version of
>   Oracle Database. For this reason, downgrades from Oracle Database 11g
>   Release 2 to Oracle Database 9i are not supported. Downgrades from
>   Oracle Database 11g Release 2 to the following versions are supported:
>    10.1.0.5  10.2.0.2, 10.2.0.3, 10.2.0.4, 10.2.0.5  11.1.0.6,
>   11.1.0.7

but this one 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17222/downgrade.htm#UPGRD12554

says:

> If you are downgrading to Oracle Database 10g Release 2 (10.2), then
>   the COMPATIBLE initialization parameter must be set to 10.2.0 or
>   lower.

thx

Comment: how about a fresh install of 10.2 (out of support for many years) and then import your data from 11g?

Comment: I do not have enough disk space to dump, the db is too big. And I would like to know more about the downgrade. But ty for your suggestion.

Comment: How do you perform backups in this case? Are talking about Petabyte?

Comment: It's a lab environment. There's no backup neither dspace to dump anything. I'm just testing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is very confusing. Also, I figured out that we cannot set it to 10.2.0 (without digits) as answered by @Balazs, doing so will throw an error stating that the COMPATIBLE parameter is not correctly set. Changing it to 10.2.0.4 was possible and it was accepted by the dbase.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, as stated in the 11.1 documentation:

[Supported Releases for Downgrading](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28300/downgrade.htm#i1010267)

Oracle mentions 10.2.0, because ideally you need not to set anything more specific (more digits). This is explained in:

**How To Change The COMPATIBLE Parameter And What Is The Significance? (Doc ID 733987.1)**

> Use only the first 3 digits for the compatible parameter unless there
>   would be some very specific instructions to do otherwise.  Patch sets
>   are normally not intended to add/change actual functionality, hence
>   there is no need to increase the compatible parameter and set the 4th
>   digit.

If you set it to 10.2.0.4.0, the downgrade should be still successful to version 10.2.0.4, but not anything lower.

Comment: Note bellow in the answer. Thx for providing me info about the downgrade.